# How to insert form data using MySqli/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

I am trying to insert form data using mysqli, php. The issue I am stuck with is that it insert '?' as the form values in the table instead of what I am typing in the form? I know I am going wrong somewhere, but I am not able to figure it out.

My additional question is :Is it safe to use mysqli statements like this to insert or select data from the database since I guess $_POST becomes a threat for injection attacks,. Is it for now enough what I am writing here to prevent attacks or do I need to add something more?

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Here is my code

**index.php**

```
<?php

        session_start();
        include('db.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

</head>

<body>


<?php

    if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login'] == 'Login') {
        $loginEmail = $_POST['loginEmail'];
        $loginPassword = $_POST['loginPassword'];

        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO dbname(password,email) VALUES ('?','?');");
        $query->bind_param("ss",$loginEmail,$loginPassword);
        $query->execute();

    }         
    ?>

        <div id="login">            
            <strong>Login</strong>

            <br/><br/>

            <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
                <table style="width:500px">                        
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="loginEmail" placeholder = "Email" required/><br/></td>
                    </tr>                    
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="password"  name="loginPassword" placeholder = "Password" required/><br/></td>

                    </tr>
                </table>

                <input style="font-weight: bold; width: 70px; height: 25px; border-radius: 5px;" type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
            </form>
        </div>       
</body>    
</html>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php

        $host = 'host';
        $user = 'user';
        $password = 'password';
        $database = 'dbname';

        $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

        if($db->connect_errno > 0){
            die('Unable to connect to database ['.$db->connect_errno.']');
        }
?>
```

Comment: you have syntax errors in your prepared statement and not checking for errors. Then you're using plain text for passwords. If you're live or intending to go live with this, don't. Use `password_hash()`.

Comment: You should not be storing plain text passwords on your database. See [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: @fred : you mean password_hash($loginPassword)?

Comment: Consult the links that @RiggsFolly gave you. It's all in there ;-) you also have an upvoted answer below. (Peter's).

Comment: `$query->execute();` => `if(!$query->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$db->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and you'll see the syntax error, btw. @BishwaroopChakraborty Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: ah, I am actually in the process of executing password_hash(). Wouldn't have taken that long, but will be accepting the answer soon :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(password,email) VALUES (?, ?);");
```

Instead of

```
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(password,email) VALUES ('?','?');");
```

ps. Order is important: in your `bind_param()` you have email and password in opposite order than in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes in your INSERT query.

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO dbname(password,email) VALUES (?,?);");
```

Also, I'd suggest you to use functions like [stripslahes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) and [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Use:

```
$loginEmail    = trim (stripslashes( $_POST['loginEmail'] ));
$loginPassword = stripslashes( $_POST['loginPassword'] );
```

Comment: `trim()` on a password? Plus, why even have to extra useless functions when using a prepared statement?

Comment: Good point! But trim can certainly be used.

Comment: See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628418/cleansing-user-passwords you'll see what I meant. Plus, if a user has a \ in their passwords or user, then what you posted may fail. The password array should not be manipulated whatsoever.